# "group by" aggregate functions with dictionary comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i have a sequence of pairs (name, score), with recurring names. i would like to get the maximum score for each name. the name labels themselves are optional for the end result. this is a working implementation:

```
from collections import defaultdict
scores = (('eyal', 76), ('alex', 50), ('oded', 90), ('eyal', 100), ('alex', 99))
distinct = defaultdict(set)
for score in scores:
    distinct[score[0]].add(score[1])
max_scores = [max(distinct[k]) for k in distinct]
print (max_scores)
```

i am wondering, can this be done in one step using dictionary comprehensions?

Comment: i understand the desire to want to reduce code, but aren't you potentially causing a maintenance nightmare for someone else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
In [22]: dict(sorted(scores))
Out[22]: {'alex': 99, 'eyal': 100, 'oded': 90}
```

This is based on the observation that, once we sort the tuples, we only want to keep the **last** tuple for every name, and `dict()` does that nicely.

Alternatively,

```
In [16]: [max(vals) for _,vals in itertools.groupby(sorted(scores), lambda x:x[0])]
Out[16]: [('alex', 99), ('eyal', 100), ('oded', 90)]
```

This is more verbose, but also more general. For example, it can be easily adapted to compute the *average* score, whereas the first solution can't.

Comment: `dict(sorted(scores))` should do the trick in one line then. [Damn I'm fast ;)]

Comment: `dict(sorted(scores))`.  [Wow, 4 seconds too slow!]

Comment: I liked the `groupby` solution too -- it scales up better to more complicated problems, even though it's not as slick at first glance.

Comment: nice.
i tested performance with timeit:
op=45.6,
groupby=59.6,
dict(sorted)=13.5,